# Can't update my app in Google Play: aapt error

Tags: android, ant, google-play

Today when I tried to upload an update of my app, I got this from Google Play console:

> UPLOAD NEW APK TO PRODUCTION
>
> Upload failed Your APK cannot be analyzed using 'aapt dump badging'.
>   Error output: Failed to run aapt dump badging: ERROR getting
>   'android:value' attribute for meta-data:attribute could not be found

I can upload normally before. I haven't made any change in AndroidManifest.xml.
The app is built via ant. I also tried building it again, even with the last-known-good code, the same error occurs.

Should I report this to Google Play team, or is it a known issue of Google Play?
Is there any work around?

Comment: Did you used the same certificate you used when you upload the app?

Comment: Yes. My ant configuration will use the same certificate everytime. Anyway, the error message isn't about certificate.

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried uploading the same APK as the current release and got the same result. So the problem is on Google's side...

Comment: This problem is neither fixed nor acknowledged https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/known-issues/24493?hl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's now acknowledged by Google:

> Some developers have reported seeing the error "Failed to run aapt dump badging: ERROR getting 'android:value' attribute for meta-data:attribute could not be found" when attempting to upload their .apk.
>
> We're working on solving this problem. In the meantime, you can try adding the "android:value" to any meta-data manifest property that lacks that attribute. See API Guides - for more information.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/known-issues/24493

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem, but managed to fix it now.
The problem is definitely in your manifest file. For me it was the Samsung MultiWindow feature. I found the solution here: [Google Code Issue 46311](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=46311)

I had to change

```
        <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_W" android:resource="@dimen/app_defaultsize_w"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_H" android:resource="@dimen/app_defaultsize_h"/>
```

into

```
        <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_W" android:value="632dp"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_H" android:value="598dp"/>
```

Worked fine since yesterday, but now i had to change it.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here after generating new apk for alpha release with same certificate I get the error (in Dutch):

Upload mislukt

Uw APK kan niet worden geanalyseerd met 'aapt dump badging'. Foutuitvoer:

Failed to run aapt dump badging:
ERROR getting 'android:value' attribute for meta-data:attribute could not be found

I found one place in my Manifest where I use android:value for samsun multiwindow support.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow"
        android:value="true" />
```

I removed that from the Manifest. generated new apk (after project clean rebuild) and got the same error. This Manifest worked in my apk when uploading a previous version two weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use

```
android:name="some string value"
```

#### Instead of

```
android:name="@string/name_of_string_resource"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when building for ionic I forgot to add the .aab extension in the command land
I entered this into the cmd line

`zipalign -v 4 app-release.aab  appname_2.0.0`

instead of

`zipalign -v 4 app-release.aab  appname_2.0.0.aab`