# Cannot update APK on Google Play

Tags: android

I'm getting this error while trying to upload my APK to Google Play:

```
Your APK cannot be analyzed using 'aapt dump badging'. Error output:
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
W/ResourceType( 4731): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b0002 (t=10 e=2) (error -75)
ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396591/cant-update-my-app-in-google-play-aapt-error) and the Google Support page but it seems different because mine is `android:icon` instead of `android:value`.

It's important that I get this update out so any help is appreciated.

For reference, and because my app is open source, I'm posting my full manifest file as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.andrewq.planets" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:value="true">

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/Roboto" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Settings Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/action_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".Settings"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/Roboto" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGalleryActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ImageGallery" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Earth Moon Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SatelliteEarth"
            android:label="Moon"
            android:parentActivityName=".SatelliteEarth"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGalleryActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ImageGallery" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Phobos Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".Phobos"
            android:label="Phobos"
            android:parentActivityName=".Phobos"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGalleryActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ImageGallery" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".PhobosImageView"
            android:label="Phobos"
            android:parentActivityName=".MarsActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.MarsActivity" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Deimos Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".Deimos"
            android:label="Deimos"
            android:parentActivityName=".Deimos"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGalleryActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ImageGallery" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".DeimosImageView"
            android:label="Phobos"
            android:parentActivityName=".MarsActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.MarsActivity" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Moon Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MoonImageView"
            android:label="Moon"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.EarthActivity" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Sun Image View -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SunImageView"
            android:label="Sun"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Sun Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SunActivity"
            android:label="Sun"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Mercury Image View -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MercuryImageView"
            android:label="Mercury"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Mercury Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MercuryActivity"
            android:label="Mercury"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Venus Image View -->
        <activity
            android:name=".VenusImageView"
            android:label="Venus"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Venus Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".VenusActivity"
            android:label="Venus"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Earth Image View -->
        <activity
            android:name=".EarthImageView"
            android:label="Earth"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Earth Image View -->
        <activity
            android:name=".EarthActivity"
            android:label="Earth"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Mars Image View -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MarsImageView"
            android:label="Mars"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MarsActivity"
            android:label="Mars"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Jupiter Image View -->
        <activity
            android:name=".JupiterActivity"
            android:label="Jupiter"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".JupiterImageView"
            android:label="Jupiter"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Saturn Image View -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SaturnActivity"
            android:label="Saturn"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SaturnImageView"
            android:label="Saturn"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Uranus Image View -->
        <activity
            android:name=".UranusActivity"
            android:label="Uranus"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".UranusImageView"
            android:label="Uranus"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Neptune Image View -->
        <activity
            android:name=".NeptuneActivity"
            android:label="Neptune"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".NeptuneImageView"
            android:label="Neptune"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Pluto Image View -->
        <activity
            android:name=".PlutoActivity"
            android:label="Pluto"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".PlutoImageView"
            android:label="Pluto"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.andrewq.planets.ImageGallery" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help Emil. I was able to figure out the problem. I ran a search for the memory address that the error gave me. It took me to my app_name string. The problem was, I had moved my english string file to values-en and made a new one for values-ru but the default folder was empty.

Answer (score 1):

There is not `android:value` parameter for the `<application>` hive in the `Manifest` file,
take a look here as to what you can specify as a parameter:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Comment: So what's missing...everything I have defined in the `<application>` hive is all allowed.

Comment: like I said there is nothing missing, the android:value parameter is not allowed.

Comment: It's all in the activities

Comment: yes you do:  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:value="true">

Comment: I just added that after getting the error...trying to fix it.